# Eclipse not Recognizing the image

Tags: android, eclipse

I copied and pasted an image  ic_menu_music.png into folder drawable.hdpi. Then i use it in some codes like :

```
setsound.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_music);
```

but it got an error :
ic_menu_music cannot be resolved or is not a field. I cleaned and built it again, but that not work. In this line  setsound.setIcon(android.R.drawable. , i press Ctrl+Space , it suggest alots except ic_menu_music.

Comment: R.drawable.ic_menu_music instead of android.R.drawable.ic_menu_music

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be (refering to your own project):

```
setsound.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_music);
```

When you use `android.R` you're looking for Android's resources, which is not correct in this case.